# Understanding goroutines synchronization

Tags: go, channel, goroutine, waitgroup

I am trying to understand the golang *channels* and *synchronization*.
When I run my program with [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector), it results in race detection.

#### My program:

```golang
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    done := make(chan struct{})
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    go func() {
        defer close(ch)
        defer close(done)
        wg.Wait()
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        x := i
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println("Value: ", x)
            ch <- x
        }()
    }
    
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case i := <-ch:
            fmt.Println("Value: ", i)
        case <- done:
            break loop
        }
    }
}
```

#### Race detector report:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c000020148 by goroutine 7:
  internal/race.Write()
      /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.16.5/libexec/src/internal/race/race.go:41 +0x125
  sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait()
      /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.16.5/libexec/src/sync/waitgroup.go:128 +0x126
  main.main.func1()
      /home/reddy/code/github.com/awesomeProject/prod.go:106 +0xc4

Previous read at 0x00c000020148 by main goroutine:
  internal/race.Read()
      /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.16.5/libexec/src/internal/race/race.go:37 +0x206
  sync.(*WaitGroup).Add()
      /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.16.5/libexec/src/sync/waitgroup.go:71 +0x219
  main.main()
      /home/reddy/code/github.com/awesomeProject/prod.go:112 +0x124

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/reddy/code/github.com/awesomeProject/prod.go:103 +0x104
==================
```

I am not able to figure out what's going wrong here.

My analysis:

1. `wg.Add(1)` is incrementing the counter
2. `wg.Done()` is called at the end of goroutine which decrements the counter
3. `ch <- x` this should be a blocking call as it's non buffered channel
4. loop should iterate till done channel has some message which happens when the `waitgroup` counter goes to zero, i.e. all the 5 goroutines published the message
5. once the counter goes to zero, `wg` goroutine will resume and done is called and once the message is consumed in the main loop, it breaks the loop and should gracefully exit.

Comment: What are on lines 112 and 106?

Comment: @BurakSerdar

wg.Add(1) -112
wg.Wait() -106

Comment: Straight from [`sync`'s doc](https://golang.org/src/sync/waitgroup.go?s=2022:2057#L43): *Note that calls [to `Add`] with a positive delta that occur when the counter is zero must happen before a `Wait`. Calls with a negative delta, or calls with a positive delta that start when the counter is greater than zero, may happen at any time. Typically this means the calls to `Add` should execute before the statement creating the goroutine or other event to be waited for.*

Comment: Your first routine closes `ch` before the waitgroup has completed, because you're incrementing the waitgroup potentially _after_ you've started a routine waiting for it. Rather than pusing onto the done channel, you can simply close it, too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program has a race between the calls to [`wg.Add`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup.Add) and the call to [`wg.Wait`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup.Wait). These calls can happen in any order. The call to `wg.Wait` does not wait for any of the goroutines when `wg.Wait` is called before the calls to `wg.Add`.

Fix by moving the calls to `wg.Add` **before** starting the goroutine that calls `wg.Wait`. This change ensures that the calls to `wg.Add` happen before the call to `wg.Wait`.

```
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    x := i
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Println("Value: ", x)
        ch <- x
    }()
}

go func() {
    defer close(ch)
    defer close(done)
    wg.Wait()
    done <- struct{}{}
}()
```

The `WaitGroup` type has code to check for this error when running under the race detector ([modeled read](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/45f251ad6cfe0a8fa1aeac0c2c8e42bfe3549c29/src/sync/waitgroup.go#L67-L72), [modeled write](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/45f251ad6cfe0a8fa1aeac0c2c8e42bfe3549c29/src/sync/waitgroup.go#L123-L129)).

Simplify the code by breaking out of the loop in the main goroutine when `ch` is closed.  The `done` channel is not needed.

```
ch := make(chan int)
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    x := i
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Println("Value: ", x)
        ch <- x
    }()
}

go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
}()

for i := range ch {
    fmt.Println("Value: ", i)
}
```

Comment: This makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to modeled read which makes totally sense now!